# Rails 3 - Join Table with not _id Columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join

I'm trying to use a join table with a foreign key that does not end with _id and points to an non id primary key. Here's what I have.

My join table looks like so:

```
[DepatmentsLocales] (
  department_id
  locale_code
  display_name
)
```

Here are my models:

```
class Locale < ActiveRecord::Base           
  has_many :departments, :through => :departments_locales
end 

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locales, :through => :departments_locales
end

class DepartmentLocale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :locale, :foreign_key => :locale_code, :primary_key => :code
end
```

Still, Rails cannot find the association. When I call department.locales I get:

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError:
>   Could not find the association :departments_locales in model Department

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've created a mix between a `has_many :through` association and a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, or perhaps just a misconfigured `has_many :through` association. Does this do what you want?

```
# Database schema for locales
# code - primary key
# other data
class Locale < ActiveRecord::Base
  # I assume you already have code to handle the primary key for this model
  has_many :department_locales, :foreign_key => :locale_code
  has_many :departments, :through => :department_locales
end 

# Database schema for departments
# id - primary key
# other data
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :department_locales
  has_many :locales, :through => :department_locales, :primary_key => :code
end

# Database schema for department_locales
# Note this isn't a join table per se; it's a fully fledged model that happens to also do joins
# id - primary key FOR THIS MODEL (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)
# department_id
# locale_code
# display_name
class DepartmentLocale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :locale, :foreign_key => :locale_code
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Functionally, it works, but I don't find it clean. I would like to avoid "id" as the primary key in the join table and not use department_locales as an Entity. I think in my case I'll fetch it using SQL.

Comment: Do note that you can set the primary key to the DepartmentLocale model table to whatever you want using the primary_key method in the model. Hope you get it all working like you want! Good luck